# Regex - That matches from String to String

Tags: python, regex

I need to get a string out of a few files, that start with:

```
line vty (digit) (digit)
```

Then there could be none, one or more newlines, with eventual text in them, until this line comes:

```
 access-class (some more text)
```

In short how do i match everything between those lines, including themselfes.

FYI: I want to do that in Python.

Attempts:

```
(?<=line vty)(.*)(?=access-class)
(?<=line vty)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\n\t]*(?=access-class)
(?<=line vty)(.*\n)*(?=access-class)
```

Examples:

```
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 6000 
 access-class ACL-4-MGMT-VTY-IN in vrf-also
 exec-timeout 30 30
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 6000
 exec-timeout 30 30
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh 
 access-class ACL-4-MGMT-VTY-IN in vrf-also
```

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: Do you have some concrete examples we can use?

Comment: Is `access-class` always present in *each* block?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew yes, it is. But i don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use single line mode (i.e. `.` matches everything, including newline characters). This can be done by precending your regex with `(?s)` or by using the `re.DOTALL` flag in Python. Since `"line vty (digits) (digits)"` can have a variable length depending on the number of digits, you cannot use a positive lookbehind.

Instead, just use the regex `(?s)line vty \d+ \d+\s*(.*?)\s*access-class` and extract the content of the first capturing group.

[Demo and step-by-step explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/ONeSrm/1)

Comment: Look at [what it looks like](https://regex101.com/r/ONeSrm/2) if the blocks before the matching one have no `access-class`. Just `.*?` is a bad idea for such organized data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that still matches OP's specification imo. Maybe the data cannot even look that way. Maybe we'll get clarification.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me. Just one question, does this include the whole line after access-class ? @timgeb

Comment: @timgeb No you are right, there is an access-class in everey line vty block.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
import re
string_1="""line vty 0 400
 session-timeout 6000
 access-class ACL-4-MGMT-VTY-IN in vrf-also
 exec-timeout 30 30
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 6000
 exec-timeout 30 30
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
 access-class ACL-4-MGMT-VTY-IN in vrf-also"""

pattern=r"line vty(.*?)access-class"

match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
for group in match:
    print(group.group())
```

output:

```
line vty 0 400
 session-timeout 6000
 access-class
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 6000
 exec-timeout 30 30
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
 access-class
```